# Navigation controller inside Admob ad close method not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack

Calling navcontroller.navigate method inside interstial ad close method works occasionally and doesnot show any error.

```
                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
 activityToFragmentCallback.openOnAdClosed(fragViewModel.getFragmentNumberToOpen());

                                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
                                navController.navigate(R.id.destination);

                            }
```

Comment: any solution for this?